# How to Stream TV channel into your Android application?

Tags: android, video-streaming

I have been streaming videos on my Android App that are on Server But I want to Stream videos that are currently running on the TV
channels as live.

If there is any way i can run live videos of TV channels into my Android App, please guide me.

I have used this URL http://blindy.tv/all.m3u to stream video but when it runs I got error, that This video can not be played.

I think this URL is fine, but my application is not able to play videos, like fetch video and then play continuously as this url is
streaming videos.

I have an assignment to show videos of a TV channel into Android App.
How can i show it.?

My Code is Following that is working fine for some video that is placed on server. but i want my code to work to display live tv
channels streaming in my android app. How can i do this as to cover my
Assignment ???

```
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Main5Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener, MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener, MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, MediaPlayer.OnVideoSizeChangedListener, SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private static final String TAG = "TAG";
    private int mVideoWidth;
    private int mVideoHeight;
    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
    private SurfaceView mPreview;
    private SurfaceHolder holder;
    private String path;

    private boolean mIsVideoSizeKnown = false;
    private boolean mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed = false;
```

/*OnCreate() function */

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main5);

        mPreview = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface);
        holder = mPreview.getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(this);
        holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }
```

/*playVideo() function */

```
    private void playVideo() {
        doCleanUp();
        try {

            path = "http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/gear1/prog_index.m3u8";

            if (path == "") {
                // Tell the user to provide a media file URL.
                Toast.makeText(
                                this,
                                "Please edit MediaPlayerDemo_Video Activity,"
                                        + " and set the path variable to your media file URL.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            Log.e("PATH", "Path = " + path);
            // Create a new media player and set the listeners
            mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
            mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder);
            mMediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
            mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            mMediaPlayer.prepare();
            mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
            mMediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(this);
            mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
    public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer arg0, int percent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBufferingUpdate percent:" + percent);

    }

    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCompletion called");
    }

    public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int width, int height) {
        Log.v(TAG, "onVideoSizeChanged called");
        if (width == 0 || height == 0) {
            Log.e(TAG, "invalid video width(" + width + ") or height(" + height + ")");
            return;
        }
        mIsVideoSizeKnown = true;
        mVideoWidth = width;
        mVideoHeight = height;
        if (mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed && mIsVideoSizeKnown) {
            startVideoPlayback();
        }
    }

    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaplayer) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPrepared called");
        mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed = true;
        if (mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed && mIsVideoSizeKnown) {
            startVideoPlayback();
        }
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceholder, int i, int j, int k) {
        Log.d(TAG, "surfaceChanged called");

    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceholder) {
        Log.d(TAG, "surfaceDestroyed called");
    }


    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        Log.d(TAG, "surfaceCreated called");
        playVideo();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        releaseMediaPlayer();
        doCleanUp();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        releaseMediaPlayer();
        doCleanUp();
    }

    private void releaseMediaPlayer() {
        if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
            mMediaPlayer.release();
            mMediaPlayer = null;
        }
    }

    private void doCleanUp() {
        mVideoWidth = 0;
        mVideoHeight = 0;
        mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed = false;
        mIsVideoSizeKnown = false;
    }
```

/*startVideoPlayback() function */

```
    private void startVideoPlayback() {
        Log.v(TAG, "startVideoPlayback");
        holder.setFixedSize(mVideoWidth, mVideoHeight);
        mMediaPlayer.start();
    }

}
```

Comment: "I want to Stream videos that are currently running on the TV channels as live" -- from Android's standpoint, there is no difference between this and "streaming videos on my Android App that are on Server". You need to find a URL that contains a legal stream of "the TV channels" that happens to be compatible with Android. Or, possibly, look into using other video playback options (ExoPlayer, libVLC) that perhaps can handle more streaming formats.

Comment: Yes, I have searched a lot, but i didn't find any live channels stream API that would provide me live streaming of any public channel.